Error in SiteWiseEdgePublisher log with MqttModule
I've setup AWS Greengrass and AWS Sitewise on a Ubuntu 24.02 VM.
In the /greengrass/v2/logs/aws.iot.SiteWiseEdgePublisher.log file I see the following error:
2024-06-21T20:45:28.465Z [INFO] (Copier) aws.iot.SiteWiseEdgePublisher: stdout. [INFO ] 2024-06-21 15:45:28.465 [com.hivemq.client.mqtt-1-1] MqttModule - Disconnected from MQTT broker at 127.0.0.1:1883, because io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:1883. {scriptName=services.aws.iot.SiteWiseEdgePublisher.lifecycle.Startup.Script, serviceName=aws.iot.SiteWiseEdgePublisher, currentState=RUNNING}

Why am I getting this error?

The connection to your localhost is being rejected. Are you positive you have a service on that port?

If SiteWise is deployed does it need MQTT service to be running on that port to work?  Why wouldn't it have the service running?  Do I need to deploy a AWS Greengrass component in order for this to work?  Why wouldn't it state that SiteWise will not work without a specific component and service?

I mean MQTT is the message broker so I would expect a message service to be running. I am only familiar with MQTT, those questions in your comment, are best answered by you.

Does this mean I have to deploy the MQTT Bridge component (aws.greengrass.clientdevices.mqtt.Bridge) to the device?

I can deploy 3 components:
aws.greengrass.clientdevices.mqtt.Bridge
aws.greengrass.clientdevices.mqtt.EMQX
aws.greengrass.clientdevices.mqtt.Moquette
Which one does SiteWise need to show the asset measurements?  Right, now I just don't see the measurement being shown, yet the "SiteWise Gateway" & "Greengrass device" seem to be active and working.

I want to get a simple OPC-UA server assets measurements to be shown.  I don't need HiveMQ because I am using OPC-UA.  Why does it want to use com.hivemq.client.mqtt-1-1?

What does the deployment documentation indicate is required?
